# iframe re sizer add position fixed

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, iframe-resizer

Am using iframe script from http://davidjbradshaw.github.io/iframe-resizer/, I would like to add position fixed to this script to make the iframe fixed at the top but am not able to achieve it.
Please help me to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just `iframe{position:fixed}` with `styles`?

Comment: Iframe tag is dynamically generated only way I can add any style is through this js file.

Comment: Even though it is dynamically generated, the above style in any `CSS` which is imported to page, will make `iframe position fix`